# Hiding status bar when presenting modals in iOs 7 leads to unwanted behaviors

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, statusbar

As mentioned by Apple documentation, I'm using the following method to hide/show the status bar in different view controllers:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
```

Now, lets say I have the following scenario:

- A & B : Master & Detail view controllers of a UISplitViewController. None of those controllers implements prefersStatusBarHidden. (Like when creating a master-detail based project)
- C : UIViewController subclass. Implements prefersStatusBarHidden returning YES;

When B presents C as a full screen modal, the status bar hides gently, but when C is dismissed, the split makes an unwanted "back to normal" effect, like moving the top bars violently. The weird thing is that this effect does not happen if the device is in portrait mode.

Check the following video to better understand what I'm trying to show here:

http://youtu.be/f5v8H0wBLJk

Here you can download the sample code I'm using:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31675938/StatusBarTest.zip

Any ideas what's happening here?